# adding a custom logback log pattern in spring boot yml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I have been looking all over and was not able to figure this out.  I need to add a custom log pattern for log output.  I can do this very easily through a logback.xml file in the resources directory and it works exactly as I want it.

However, I would like to be able to do this throughout he application.yml file if that is possible.  Mostly because I would like to externalize it in one place.

I have the normal logging stuff in application.yml as below:

```
    #logging definitions
```

## use the hierarchy tree to set logging levels

logging:
  file: logs/accountservice.log
  level:
    org:
      springframework: 'INFO'
    com:
      mangofactory:
        swagger:
          scanners: 'OFF'
      cisco:
        services: 'DEBUG'

The log pattern is like this:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 1.2 it's not possible to customize the pattern using `application.yml`. There is a feature request open to improve this (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1788).

Comment: now (spring-boot 1.3.1) available `logging.pattern.console` configuration property. Default pattern you can find in `spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml`

Comment: @deFreitas It is (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/ under `# LOGGING`)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `logging.pattern.console` and `logging.pattern.file` for customizing the log pattern to use on the console and file, respectively. For example, if you add this to your `application.yml`:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg%n'
```

Your console logs would be like:

```
16:09:43.299 Log message
```

Checkout the Spring Boot documentation on [Customizing log configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration) for more information.